# How to subscribe to an Observable with three different filter conditions

Tags: filter, rxjs

I'm seeing this code, which seems non-compliant to me. I mean, three different subscribes to the same observable in order to handle three `filter` conditions?

My question is: what's the best way of refactoring into one clean `pipe` and `subscribe`.

Perhaps a `merge()` ?

```js
public ngOnInit() {
    this.broadcastService.inProgress$
        .pipe(
            filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None),
            takeUntil(this._destroying$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.setLoginDisplay();
        });
    this.broadcastService.inProgress$
        .pipe(filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status !== InteractionStatus.None))
        .subscribe((result: InteractionStatus) => {
            console.log(result);
        });
    this.broadcastService.inProgress$
        .pipe(filter((status: InteractionStatus) => status === InteractionStatus.None))
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.setLoginDisplay();
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do both of the "subscribe logic" in the same subscription:

```js
public ngOnInit() {
    this.broadcastService.inProgress$.pipe(
        filter(status => status === InteractionStatus.None),
        takeUntil(this._destroying$),
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.setLoginDisplay();
        console.log(result);
    });
  }
```

---

Depending on what `setLoginDisplay()` does, you may be able to express `loginDisplay$` as an observable without explicitly subscribing:

```js
public loginDisplay$ = this.broadcastService.inProgress$.pipe(
    filter(status => status === InteractionStatus.None),
    map(status => /* logic the emits the appropriate loginDisplay */),
    tap(result => console.log(result))
);
```

Then in the template, you just use the `async` pipe:

```html
<div *ngIf="loginDisplay | async as loginDisplay">
  {{ loginDisplay }}
</div>
```

This approach does not require `ngOnInit`, `this._destroying$`, or an explicit `.subscribe()`.

Comment: What you suggest makes sense, thank you. And btw, when he first created his PR we were like "huh?" But will his code even work with 3 different subscribes ? I mean, will it actually hit those 3 different pipes  -and also subscribe 3 times ?

Comment: It looks like all 3 subscribes would fire.  Actually, 2 of them don't actually unsubscribe :-o

Comment: `tap((result: InteractionStatus) => {
                         this.setLoginDisplay();
                        console.log(result);
                    }),`

Comment: and I also think we should introduce a tap() operator to handle his subscribe code, in which case we can leave the subscribe() cleanly on its own.

Comment: Turns out that `this.loginDisplay` is a boolean. Then if truthy, at some point he launches a Material Modal. This is what we're dealing with atm.